# Divs diferentes em loop

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Deparo-me com o seguinte problema, com o codigo abaixo eu pretendia acrescentar mais campos sem repetir as `divs`.

Codigo:

```
<? foreach($itens as $myrow){ ?>
                    <div id="LISTA1_FUNDO_PRETO">
                    TITULO</div>
                <?}?>
```

O que eu realmente queria era fazer isto, sem `divs`:

```
<? foreach($itens as $myrow){ ?>
                        <div id="LISTA1_FUNDO_PRETO">
                        TITULO</div>

<div id="LISTA1_FUNDO_BRANCO">
                        TITULO</div>
                    <?}?>
```

Comment: Agora to em dúvida você quer as Divs com id numerados ou colocar uma class em cada div?

Comment: a sua pergunta está na fronteira entre "fechar" ou manter aberta.. Se puder responder  a pergunta do @Adir, acho que será mais válida a questão.

Comment: colocar uma class em cada div, para fazer este efeito: [link](http://prntscr.com/6xg2tf) ou seja, em cada dado que é inserido, primeiro vem o fundo branco, depois o preto, e depois volta o branco e assim sucessivamente ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de tudo, não tente usar o `id` quando no lugar deveria ser `class`. Id's iguais tornam o HTML inválido. O correto é usar o `class`, principalmente se a intenção é utilizar-se da propriedade no css.

Utilize o `foreach` dessa forma:

```
<? foreach($itens as $index => $myrow) {
  $className = $index % 2 == 0 ? "LISTA1_FUNDO_PRETO" : "LISTA1_FUNDO_BRANCO" ?>
  <div class="<? echo $className ?>">TITULO</div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```
    $classes_color = [
        '0' => 'bg-info', 
        '1' => 'bg-success', 
        '2' => 'bg-warning', 
        '3' => 'bg-danger', 
        '4' => 'bg-info',
        '5' => 'bg-secondary'
    ]
```

?>

```
<p><h4 class="mt-4 mb-2">Roles</h4> </p>

<div class="row">
        <?php $x=0; foreach($roles as $role) : ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <div class="small-box <?= $classes_color[$x]?>">
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>Role name</p>
                    <h3><?= $role->roles->NAME ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="small-box-footer">Register Date: <?= $role->roles->REGISTER_DATE ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $x++; endforeach ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).